# Use the equality $x^n- 1$ to prove $x^k+1$.

Tags: number-theory

Use the equality 
$$
x^{n}-1 = (x-1)\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+ \cdots + x+1\right)
$$
to prove that for odd natural number $k$, 
$$
x^{k}+1 = (x+1)\left(x^{k-1}-x^{k-2}+\cdots-x+1\right)
$$

I have no idea how to solve this one...

Comment: Just put $-x$ in your equality.

Comment: $x^k+1=x^k-(-1)=[x-(-1)][x^{k-1}-x^{k-2}+...+1]$